# problem with Bluetooth 5.3 dongle on Ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04

Using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and it is up to date.
I opened Settings, clicked Bluetooth, on the panel to the right it said: No Bluetooth Found, plug in a dongle to use Bluetooth. So I bought a Bluetooth 5.3 compatible dongle and plugged it into a USB port. The wee light on the dongle flashed several times then stayed on and the Settings->Bluetooth panel changed to: Bluetooth Turned Off, Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers.

At that point the toggle switch at the top of the screen was on the left side so I clicked on the right side. The switch moved to the right side and the message said: Bluetooth Turned Off, Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers. Huh? I had just toggled the switch and it's still off?  Very strange!!!!!!!!!!!!!

So I toggled the switch again and moved it to the left side. The message changed to: Airplane Mode is on, Bluetooth is disabled when airplane mode is on. And a button titled Turn Off Airplane Mode appeared.

So I clicked the Turn Off Airplane Mode button and got the Bluetooth Turned Off, Turn on to connect devices and receive file transfers.

At no point did I see anything like "Scanning for Bluetooth devices, this may take a few minutes....". No whirlygigs spinning to indicate something happening.

[My system hardware specs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzs1MoMML5P0o5DB-gKx7kmosnFspoIM/view?usp=sharing)

[My system hardware specs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzs1MoMML5P0o5DB-gKx7kmosnFspoIM/view?usp=sharing) is the output from "sudo lshw" when my USB 5.3 dongle is plugged in. It's ~580 lines and probably more than requested but ya never know. In that file I see

> ```
>             *-usb
> ```

```
                  description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                  product: general adapter
                  vendor: Actions
                  physical id: 1
                  bus info: usb@1:1.1
                  version: 88.91
                  serial: ACTIONS1234
                  capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                  configuration: driver=btusb maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
```

which is my BT5.3 dongle. With the dongle unplugged sudo lshw | grep -i "ACTIONS" returns a blank.  With the dongle inserted the same command finds lines for the dongle which proves only that the system sees it when it's there and doesn't see it when it's gone.

[My system hardware specs](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pzs1MoMML5P0o5DB-gKx7kmosnFspoIM/view?usp=sharing) also shows a Logitech unifying receiver dongle and the Logitech K580 wireless keyboard and M720 Triathlon mouse it serves. Those 2 are the only USB dongles in the system and I suspect they may be at odds with each other. I reported trouble with the mouse in a thread I started ~1 month ago. The problems mostly went away when I updated from Ubuntu 20.xx to 22.04 but not completely, mainly that the wheel doesn't scroll the screen properly. Looking further into that today...

```
~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i "error"
[    0.645649] RAS: Correctable Errors collector initialized.
[    9.074185] EXT4-fs (sda5): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro. Quota mode: none.
[58528.772485] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:405E.0004: Couldn't get wheel multiplier (error -110)
[222518.808683] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:405E.0004: Couldn't get wheel multiplier (error -110)
[273770.417745] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:405E.0004: Couldn't get wheel multiplier (error -110)
[280809.085517] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:405E.0004: Couldn't get wheel multiplier (error -110)
[297332.046910] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:405E.0004: Couldn't get wheel multiplier (error -110)
[305550.133903] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:405E.0004: Couldn't get wheel multiplier (error -110)

~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth
[296996.432303] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[296996.432342] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[296996.432344] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[296996.432351] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[296996.432355] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[296996.432360] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[312427.210137] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[312427.210143] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[312427.210149] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Uh-oh. I pasted the wrong output under the 2 "dmesg" commands in the box above. Fixed now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I can understand your frustration. Could you kindly post your system specifications so that we can help you fix your issue?

Comment: Thank you for your interest Arjun. Please see the link added to my post.

Answer (score 3):

Got the same problem, Bluetooth chip (ATS2851) manufacturer made a bug in their firmware, Windows ignore it but Linux get stuck. Guys developing Linux kernels working to solve this, so i believe it will be done in 6.3+ or something kernels. You can read more [here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/bluetooth/bluetooth-next.git/commit/?id=0bb039f39058) and [here](https://marc.info/?l=linux-bluetooth&w=2&r=1&s=ats2851&q=b).
[This](https://www.linuxcompatible.org/story/xanmod-linux-kernel-618-released/) alternative kernel mod already fixed this problem.

Comment: Thanks Elven. I am glad to hear some progress is being made on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded my ubuntu version from 20.04 to 22.04 few months ago. I had problems connecting my bluetooth headset after the upgrade. In my case, the devices were showing but not connecting, so I started searching the internet and found an app called blueman in the software center. It solved my problems. This is not a solution but it solved my problem. Maybe it will work for you too. Good luck :)

Comment: Thank you myrnz. I tried blueman earlier and came to the conclusion my hardware or Ubuntu isn't connecting properly with the dongle as it doesn't even scan for nearby BT devices. So the problem is deeper than I originally imagined. I'm sure blueman will work nicely once the root problem is fixed.

Comment: @koobleyecan you're welcome, i hope your problem is solved